# sort count different arrays within a given field of numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, count, time-complexity

there are m arrays containing number in range 1-n.
the size of the the whole M groups is n.
means size(m1) + size(m2) ... + size(Mn) = n
the arrays needs to be sorted and returned sepretly.

the problem is, it needs to be in O(n) and not O(m+n)
if you cnocat the arrays and do a count sort, you end up with a O(n) but how can you return the groups sepretly and not as a sorted array of all n values?

Comment: Decorate each number to indicate which array it belongs to (which is O(n)), radix sort the decorated numbers (which is O(n)), then separate into groups based on decoration (which is O(n)). Sum = 3 * O(n) = O(n).

Comment: In this case `O(n) = O(m+n)` unless you allow M to include zero-length arrays.